# Not able to start TitanGraph with Cassandra in embedded mode

Tags: java, titan

I am using this in a Java project; I was able to start ad work with TitanGraph using BerkeleyDB as the in memory DB. Because of its licensing, I started with Apachec Cassandra. It is working in standalone mode. However trying to run it in emebedded mode is throwing this error

```
      Configuration conf = new BaseConfiguration();
    //conf.setProperty("storage.backend","cassandra");
    //conf.setProperty("storage.hostname","127.0.0.1");-->Works
    conf.setProperty("storage.backend","embeddedcassandra");
    conf.setProperty("storage.cassandra-config-dir","file://d:/Program_Files/apache-cassandra-2.0.8/conf/cassandra.yaml");
    //conf.setProperty("storage.setup-time",100);//Currenlty a bug to run Cassendra Emndedded ??
    conf.setProperty("ids.block-size",1000000);
    //conf.setProperty("storage.batch-loading",true);
    conf.setProperty("storage.buffer-size",1024);
    conf.setProperty("autotype","none");
    graph = TitanFactory.open(conf);
```

Error that is coming is

```
Cannot locate ./conf/cassandra.yaml
```

Fatal configuration error; unable to start. See log for stacktrace.

Comment: Which version of Titan are you using?

Comment: I have tested with both latest 0.5.0-M1 as well as 0.4.4 ( Maven titan-core) and titan-cassandra

Comment: The default value "./conf/cassandra.yaml" is specific to 0.5.0-M1.  0.4.4 had "./config/cassandra.yaml".  Assuming you're still using 0.5.0-M1, try replacing storage.cassandra-config-dir with storage.conf-file (the option was renamed between 0.4.4 and 0.5.0-M1).  Right now it looks like you're using a config intended for 0.4.4 and getting an error suggesting 0.5.0-M1 is in use.

Comment: Thanks it started up; However some other errors are coming in emebedded mode; maybe some classpath issue (thoug I am using maven dependecy only; I will check and revet)700  [main] ERROR org.apache.cassandra.cql3.QueryProcessor  - Unable to initialize MemoryMeter (jamm not specified as javaagent). 
706  [main] ERROR org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon  - Exception encountered during startup
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.googlecode.concurrentlinkedhashmap.ConcurrentLinkedHashMap$Builder.maximumWeightedCapacity(J)Lcom/googlecode/concurrentlinkedhashmap/ConcurrentLinkedHashMap$Builder;

Comment: Sounds like you've changed the Guava version from 15.0 to something incompatible.  This is becoming a discussion thread without a crisp single answer, and you already cross-posted this to the aureliusgraphs list, so let's just continue on there.  thanks.

Comment: Thanks; I iwll post it there